# delete row from selected gridview and database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i am trying to delete a row from the gridview and database...
It should be deleted if a delte linkbutton is clicked in the gridview..
I am gettin the row index as follows:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
  GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
  if (row != null)
  {
    LinkButton LinkButton1 = (LinkButton)sender;

    // Get reference to the row that hold the button
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)LinkButton1.NamingContainer;

    // Get row index from the row
    int rowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
    string str = rowIndex.ToString();
    //string str = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    RemoveData(str); //call the delete method

  }
}
```

now i want to delete it... so i am having problems with this code.. i get an error

Must declare the scalar variable "@original_MachineGroupName"... any suggestions

```
private void RemoveData(string item)
{
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=JAGMIT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;
  Initial Catalog=SumooHAgentDB;Integrated Security=True");
  string sql = "DELETE FROM [MachineGroups] WHERE [MachineGroupID] = 
                @original_MachineGroupID;
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@original_MachineGroupID", item);

  conn.Open();

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  conn.Close();
}
```

> Blockquote

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SumooHAgentDBConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT MachineGroups.MachineGroupID, MachineGroups.MachineGroupName,
    MachineGroups.MachineGroupDesc, MachineGroups.TimeAdded, 
    MachineGroups.CanBeDeleted, COUNT(Machines.MachineName) AS Expr1, 
    DATENAME(month, (MachineGroups.TimeAdded - 599266080000000000) / 864000000000) + 
    SPACE(1) + DATENAME(d, (MachineGroups.TimeAdded - 599266080000000000) / 
     864000000000) + 
    ', ' + DATENAME(year, (MachineGroups.TimeAdded - 599266080000000000) /
    864000000000) AS Expr2 FROM MachineGroups FULL OUTER JOIN Machines ON 
    Machines.MachineGroupID = MachineGroups.MachineGroupID GROUP BY 
    MachineGroups.MachineGroupID, MachineGroups.MachineGroupName, 
    MachineGroups.MachineGroupDesc, MachineGroups.TimeAdded, 
    MachineGroups.CanBeDeleted" 
  DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [MachineGroups] WHERE 
                  [MachineGroupID] =@original_MachineGroupID" >
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="@original_MachineGroupID" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="@original_MachineGroupName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="@original_MachineGroupDesc" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="@original_CanBeDeleted" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="@original_TimeAdded" Type="Int64" />
        </DeleteParameters>   
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I still get an error : Must declare the scalar variable "`@original_MachineGroupID`"

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding an @original_MachineGroupName parameter to your query.  Your query references multiple variables, and you've only added one of them.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@original_MachineGroupID", item);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@original_MachineGroupName", itemName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@original_MachineGroupDesc", itemDesc);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@original_CanBeDeleted", true);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@original_TimeAdded", time);
```

You'll need to find the extra information to satisfy your query, or else change your query to remove the need for them.

Comment: so i need to pass all the values like itemname, itemdesc and so on.. individually?? I am just neding the row number to be deleted..

Is there an easier method to do this..

Thanks

Comment: Well, your delete query is specifically checking for these things. My guess is that the row cannot be uniquely identified without all of this information. You either have to simplify your delete query to only require the ID, or else you have to pass it all the information it needs.

Comment: I have simplifies the delete query as above.. stll it does not delete.. is this the only way to delete rows...please help

Comment: You've simplified the query, but now you've added multiple parameters.  The number of parameters needs to match the actual number that you are using in the query.  The names also need to match... add the "@" symbol in front of the name of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have several parameters in you query i.e. @original_MachineGroupName but are only adding one actual parameter to you command object.  You will need one for each parameter in the query.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will delete the row from the database if the string you are passing to method is primary or unique key in table:

```
string sql = "DELETE FROM [MachineGroups] WHERE [MachineGroupID] = 
                  @original_MachineGroupID";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@original_MachineGroupID", item);
```

Comment: sir i tried this command.. it is still not working..
I kno the command is right... still can u help me..
is there some prob with my .aspx page??
I have posted the code on top..

Answer (score 0):

Watch your databinding also. If you delete a row from the database, that doesn't delete the data from the gridview. You will need to re-fetch your data and databind it again.

Comment: sir the delete function itself is not working.. please can u tell me a simple way to do this...
I dont kno why anything is not working??

Comment: the main problem i think it is not getting the machinegroup id it has to delete... insted it is getting the row number.. so when i slick on delete nothing seems to happen...