# Getting error when deleting row from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

My ASPX code is:

```
<asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" 
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="Gridview1_RowDeleting" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true">
        <Columns>


        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

     <%-- <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>--%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data Type">
            <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddldatatype" runat="server">
                  <asp:ListItem>varchar</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>int</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>numeric</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>uniqueidentifier</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>char</asp:ListItem>
                  </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click"/>
             <asp:Button ID="ButtonDel" runat="server" Text="Delete Row" OnClick="ButtonDel_Click" />
             <input type="hidden" runat="server" value="0" id="hiddencount" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdelete" runat="server" >Delete</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

and my C# code is:

```
 protected void Gridview1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
     {

         Gridview1.DeleteRow((int)Gridview1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
         Gridview1.DataBind();


     }
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
            Gridview1.DataBind();
        }
```

I am getting the error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

Comment: no question - just code and again another duplicate of the same question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/1485570/76051 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/1521282/76051) by another annonymous-user....

Comment: Please edit your post and add a question, your problem and some more relative information.

Comment: You updated your post, but the question is still missing...

Comment: no I (and Patrik) edited the post and no I didn't add a question because I won't edit my guesses in there

Comment: @user913947: The problem is the program will delete that row after you come out of RowDeleting Handler. But the row is not existing as you have already deleted in your DeleteRow method and again databinded it. So please add e.Cancel=true after your DataBind() statement which will not allow the program to delete the row. And it will surely work. Cheers !

Comment: I dont know why these guys dont understand your question and have negative voted it.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is the following line:

```
 Gridview1.DeleteRow((int)Gridview1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
```

and in there the

```
Gridview1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]
```

this cannot work, just look up the [DataKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys%28VS.80%29.aspx)-property and the [DeleteRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.deleterow.aspx)-method
I guess what you *want to do* is

```
Gridview1.DeleteRow(e.RowIndex)
```

but even here you should check the Index!